# MySQL Select rows that contain every value in a list

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to create a SELECT statement that allows me to select all the rows in a table that contain every id in a list of ids.  For example, I have a two-column table, one with primary id and one with a foreign key fid.  Say I have a list [1, 2, 3, 4], then I want every row that has a foreign key 1 and 2 and 3 and 4.  The problem is the list can be any size, so I can't simply do four joins.  I tried using a SELECT...WHERE...IN statement but that uses or statements and not and.

Is there something similar to a WHERE...IN that performs AND on every value in the list?  Or could I just make a loop to join where every row has each fid?

Comment: It might be good to edit your question to include sample table rows. "I want every row that has a foreign key 1 and 2" -- Do you mean a 3-column table with 2 foreign keys?  5 columns and 4 keys? One field in one row can't contain 4 values.

Comment: do it with JOINs and WHERE ... IN. If you're running a SQL query in a loop you've failed.

Comment: DId you find the answer to this yet? If yes may you post it here please?